# Greater than for INET IP address field in PostgreSQL Version > 9

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

So I have wrote my own lookups for PostgreSQL INET field in my DRF App as Django does not natively support those PostgreSQL specific fields.
I use my own IP field in my objects to support my own lookups.

All my lookup work find, except for those two:

```
class HostGreaterOrEqual(Lookup):
    """ Lookup to check if an IP address is greater than or equal. Used for net ranges"""
    lookup_name = "host_greater_or_equal"

    def as_sql(self, qn, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(qn, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(qn, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "%s >= %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
    
class HostLessOrEqual(Lookup):
    """ Lookup to check if an IP address is less than or equal. Used for net ranges"""
    lookup_name = "host_less_or_equal"

    def as_sql(self, qn, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(qn, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(qn, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "%s <= %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

In my models I have a address and address_end field to store IP Ranges. I wanted to use those lookups above to make the proper queries like this:

```
items = queryset.filter(
                Q(address__host_greater_or_equal=value)
                & Q(address_end__host_less_or_equal=value)
            )
```

In the documentation for [PostgreSQL Version 9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-net.html) I can see the operators for "is lass or equal" and "is greater or equal".
But if I check the documentation for [Version 15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) it seems like those have been removed.

Was that functionality simply removed or is there something similar that I have not found yet?

Comment: The manual was restructured between 9.6 and 15. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) "The IP network address types, cidr and inet, support the usual comparison operators shown in Table 9.1" And Table 9.1 links to: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-OP-TABLE

Answer (score 2):

From the [v13.0 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/13.0/#id-1.11.6.14.5.12):

> Reformat tables containing **[function and operator information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions.html)** for better clarity (Tom Lane)

So they aren't in [their usual place](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-net.html) in the documentation since then, but they're [still available](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-OP-TABLE).

```sql
select inet '192.168.1.5' <  inet '192.168.1.6' as "less than",
       inet '192.168.1.5' >  inet '192.168.1.6' as "greater than",
       inet '192.168.1.5' <= inet '192.168.1.6' as "less than or equal",
       inet '192.168.1.5' >= inet '192.168.1.6' as "greater than or equal";
-- less than | greater than | less than or equal | greater than or equal
-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------------
-- t         | f            | t                  | f

show server_version;
--          server_version
-------------------------------------
-- 15rc2 (Debian 15~rc2-1.pgdg110+1)
```

Which you can test on different versions here: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FvxMu9DX).

---

You can always check the system tables to make sure what's really available

```sql
select * 
from pg_catalog.pg_operator 
where oprname in ('<=','>=') 
and oprcode::text ilike '%network%';
-- oid  | oprname | oprnamespace | oprowner | oprkind | oprcanmerge | oprcanhash | oprleft | oprright | oprresult | oprcom | oprnegate |  oprcode   |   oprrest   |     oprjoin
--------+---------+--------------+----------+---------+-------------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------------
-- 1204 | <=      |           11 |       10 | b       | f           | f          |     869 |      869 |        16 |   1206 |      1205 | network_le | scalarlesel | scalarlejoinsel
-- 1206 | >=      |           11 |       10 | b       | f           | f          |     869 |      869 |        16 |   1204 |      1203 | network_ge | scalargesel | scalargejoinsel
```

Or look them up in `psql` with `\do+`

```sql
\do+ <= inet inet
--                                         List of operators
--   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |  Function  |    Description
--------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+--------------------
-- pg_catalog | <=   | inet          | inet           | boolean     | network_le | less than or equal

\do+ >= inet inet
--                                           List of operators
--   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |  Function  |      Description
--------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------
-- pg_catalog | >=   | inet          | inet           | boolean     | network_ge | greater than or equal
```

`psql -E` shows `\do+` finds it using the following query, that you can issue in a different client.

```sql
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  o.oprname AS "Name",
  CASE WHEN o.oprkind='l' THEN NULL ELSE pg_catalog.format_type(o.oprleft, NULL) END AS "Left arg type",
  CASE WHEN o.oprkind='r' THEN NULL ELSE pg_catalog.format_type(o.oprright, NULL) END AS "Right arg type",
  pg_catalog.format_type(o.oprresult, NULL) AS "Result type",
  o.oprcode AS "Function",
  coalesce(pg_catalog.obj_description(o.oid, 'pg_operator'),
           pg_catalog.obj_description(o.oprcode, 'pg_proc')) AS "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_operator o
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = o.oprnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t0 ON t0.oid = o.oprleft
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nt0 ON nt0.oid = t0.typnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t1 ON t1.oid = o.oprright
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nt1 ON nt1.oid = t1.typnamespace
WHERE o.oprname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(>=)$' COLLATE pg_catalog.default
  AND pg_catalog.pg_operator_is_visible(o.oid)
  AND (t0.typname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(inet)$' COLLATE pg_catalog.default
        OR pg_catalog.format_type(t0.oid, NULL) OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(inet)$' COLLATE pg_catalog.default)
  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t0.oid)
  AND (t1.typname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(inet)$' COLLATE pg_catalog.default
        OR pg_catalog.format_type(t1.oid, NULL) OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(inet)$' COLLATE pg_catalog.default)
  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t1.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```